# Adding and removing an array to local storage, then retrieving the individual array items somehow?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, local-storage

I'm working on a library that the user can add and remove books to. This requires local storage. I successfully added the library to local storage but I have no idea how to access and modify the individual local storage array items.

I have a function to add new books to the library and then send the library to local storage:

```
    const addBook = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newBook = createBook();
    updateLibrary(newBook);

    newBook = `${newBook.title}`;
    console.log(newBook);

    localStorage.setItem('library', JSON.stringify(theLibrary));
    
    newBookForm.style.display = 'none';

    
}
```

Then, I set the library to be displayed to the user equal to the library from local storage:

```
// Displays the library on cards
function showLib() {
    for (let i = 0; i < theLibrary.length; i++) {
            
            if (localStorage.length > 0) {
                let library = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('library'));

                theLibrary = library;

            }
```

Now, that all works and what not but I can't figure out how to remove a specific item from an array within local storage. Here's my attempt at a solution within my remove button click function:

```
toggleRemove.onclick = function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.parentNode);
                deleteThis = e.target.parentNode;

                for (i = 0; i < theLibrary.length; i++) {
                    let library = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('library'));
                    console.log(library[i]);
                    let newLibrary = library.splice(i, 1);
                    localStorage.setItem('remove', JSON.stringify(newLibrary));

                    localStorage.removeItem(newLibrary);

                }

                
                deleteThis.remove();
                removeBook(deleteThis);
                }
```

I'm banging my head against the wall here. I can't seem to target the item I want. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: There are quite a few methods in there that are not defined for us. If these are pertinent to the question please add them to your question.

Comment: Do you mean to save under a different name after removing the item? That will be a different library (you will have two). (Edit: I think you can also remove `let newLibrary = `, and just keep the right hand side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not to try and remove the item directly from localstorage. You can follow the immutable state flow for this.

Follow these steps:

- Set the localstorage with the library array like you did on your first snippet  `localStorage.setItem('library', JSON.stringify(theLibrary));`
- Then on your update function first retrieve the library data from localstorage. `let library = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('library'));`
- Now let's say you want to remove the `i` index from the array with the splice method. `library = library.splice(i, 1);` (store in the same variable, no need for new variable).
- Now set this updated library in the same key as before in the localstorage. `localStorage.setItem('library', JSON.stringify(library));`
- Now you you can consume from your `showLib` function from the same
  way `let library = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('library'));`